# XSLT: Use Named template to copy XSD to XSD

Tags: xslt

I have the XSD content in [this file](http://www.pesc.org/library/docs/standards/Sector%20Library/AcademicRecord_v1.4.0.xsd).

Using this xsl, I can copy the contents of the desired element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
    <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:element">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@type, 'core')">
            core
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@type, 'AcRec')">
            AcRec
        </xsl:when>         
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The idea is to select a particular node in an xsd, and generate all the supporting elements into a single file by looking them up based on the type value.

The desired output should ultimately look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:core="urn:org:pesc:core:CoreMain:v1.2.0" xmlns:AcRec="urn:org:pesc:sector:AcademicRecord:v1.1.0">
<xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SchoolAssignedPersonID" type="core:SchoolAssignedPersonIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="SIN" type="core:SINIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="NSN" type="core:NSNIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="AgencyAssignedID" type="core:AgencyAssignedIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="RecipientAssignedID" type="core:RecipientAssignedIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="SSN" type="core:SSNType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Birth" type="core:BirthType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="core:NameType"/>
        <xs:element name="AlternateName" type="core:NameType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="HighSchool" type="AcRec:HighSchoolType" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Contacts" type="AcRec:ContactsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Gender" type="core:GenderType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Residency" type="AcRec:ResidencyType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Deceased" type="core:DeceasedType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="NoteMessage" type="core:NoteMessageType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="SchoolAssignedPersonIDType" />
<xs:simpleType name="SINIDType" />
<xs:simpleType name="NSNIDType" />
<xs:simpleType name="AgencyAssignedIDType" />
<xs:complexType name="HighSchoolType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OrganizationName" type="core:OrganizationNameType"/>
        <xs:element name="OPEID" type="core:OPEIDType"/>
        <xs:element name="NCHELPID" type="core:NCHELPIDType"/>
        <xs:element name="IPEDS" type="core:IPEDSType"/>
        <xs:element name="ATP" type="core:ATPType"/>
        <xs:element name="FICE" type="core:FICEType"/>
        <xs:element name="ACT" type="core:ACTType"/>
        <xs:element name="CCD" type="core:CCDType"/>
        <xs:element name="CEEBACT" type="core:CEEBACTType"/>
        <xs:element name="CSIS" type="core:CSISType"/>
        <xs:element name="USIS" type="core:USISType"/>
        <xs:element name="ESIS" type="core:ESISType"/>
        <xs:element name="DUNS" type="core:DUNSType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="OrganizationNameType" />
<xs:simpleType name="OPEIDType" />
```

The idea I was was to use a combination of templates - the copy first to grab the element & sub-elements (exluding xs:annotations and xs:restrictions).  The second template would iterate over the xs:element contents of an element to retrieve the reference from the other file.  Additionally, when xs:groups are encountered, the xs:group ref element is to be replaced with the contents of the  element in the xs:group definition.

Comment: You somehow forgot to mention what you are trying to achieve. Can you at least post the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I think you are missing the correct handling of namespaces in your XSL stylesheet.

The "`complexType`" template you made does not match the "`xs:complexType`" nodes have. You must declare the `xs` namespace, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

and you must use it, too:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:element">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Once I made that change, your stylesheet gave me:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>core core core core core core core core core AcRec AcRec core AcRec core core</xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Which clearly shows that the template is being used. XSL always uses the *most specific* template it can find for any given node, just like CSS uses the most specifc rule it can find.

The `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">` is a lot less specific than the `<xsl:template match="complexType">`, but unless you use the `xs` namespace, the latter just does not match anything.

P.S.: A few remarks:

- `<xsl:otherwise>` is not mandatory, you can leave it out if it is empty.
- there is no need to use `<xsl:call-template name="copy" />`. Once you define what output you'd like to see, we can get rid of that in favor of a cleaner approach
- as your `<xsl:when>` tests I'd recommend `substring-before(@type, ':') = 'core'` over `contains(@type, 'core')`. The latter is more error-prone.
- it is probably just for of the example, but you should use `<xsl:text>core</xsl:text>` to avoid unnecessary whitespace in the output.

Comment: Thanks - I've been struggling with this, and really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "force" it to use a template with a `match` attribute. Such template will apply to all elements that match it, and only to those elements. So if some of those child elements that matched `node()` are `complexType`, it will be applied automatically.

You can give it a `name`, of course, and then use `<xsl:call-template name="...">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="complexType"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[local-name() != 'complexType']|@*"/>
```

This will output all complex nodes before the rest. Alternatively, to change the order, you need to do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[local-name() != 'complexType']|@*"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="complexType"/>
```